# Redirect multiprocessing.Process output properly

Tags: windows, subprocess, python-multiprocessing, python-3.9

I want to spawn a process and redirect its stdout/stderr.
With subprocess.Popen this example seems to work properly but not with multiprocessing.Process.

main script:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, set_start_method
import subprocess
import os
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))


def sub():
    import sys
    sys.stdout = None
    sys.stderr = None
    sys.__stdout__ = None
    sys.__stderr__ = None
    subprocess.run(["tasklist"])
    print("Test") # is not printed. OK!


if __name__ == "__main__":
    set_start_method("spawn")
    

    ## multiprocessing.Process: tasklist output IS printed on console and is not redirected via sys.stdout. Why?
    p = Process(target=sub)
    p.start()
    p.join()
    
    ## subprocess.Popen: tasklist output is printed to the file
    fh = open("out", "w")
    p2 = subprocess.Popen("python popen.py",
                          stdout=fh)
    fh.close()
```

Content of popen.py:

```
import subprocess
if __name__ == "__main__":
    subprocess.run(["tasklist"])
```